# search url for matching string in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, search

I'm trying to search url for a matching string with jquery and if it matches add these classes to an html element. I have this code:

```
$(function () {
 var adminNav = [ "book_values", "lsi_print_costs", "book_specs"];
 var url = window.location.href;
 if (url.search(adminNav) > 0) {
    $('li#nav-admin.dark-nav').addClass('active');
    $('#print-admin').addClass('in');
 }
});
```

Any help would be greatly apperciated

Comment: search will return -1 if the string is not found, search also looks like it takes a regex object, not a string, (although it will convert the string to regex object) might be better to create a regex object?https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(function () {
 var adminNav = [ "book_values", "lsi_print_costs", "book_specs"];
 var isExist = false;
 var url = window.location.href;
for(var i=0; i<adminNav.length; i++ )
{
 if (url.search(adminNav[i]) > 0 && !isExist) {
   isExist = true;
 }
}

if(isExist)
{
 $('li#nav-admin.dark-nav').addClass('active');
 $('#print-admin').addClass('in');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript:

```
if(window.location.search.indexOf("book_values") >=0) {
    $('li#nav-admin.dark-nav').addClass('active');
    $('#print-admin').addClass('in');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .map() to search if the `window.location.href` contains any value in the array.

```
var adminNav = ["book_values", "lsi_print_costs", "book_specs"];
var found = false;
adminNav.map(function (val) {
    if (window.location.href.contains(val) && !found) {
        found = true;
        $('li#nav-admin.dark-nav').addClass('active');
        $('#print-admin').addClass('in');
    }
});
```